# Terminal configuration is incorrect

Tags: terminal, zsh, tmux, iterm2

I'm having issues with two parts of my Terminal installation in particular.

The first is the prompt area. Look at how on each new line it says `108%` instead of `>`. I'd like to know how I can switch that back to `>`.

[image: Image of Terminal - Look at the 108% symbol]
![Image of Terminal][1]

The second issue is that I'm having issues setting my `$EDITOR` variable for tmux to work.

I've worked and set up the .tmux.conf file, and used the following line to attempt to set the editor:

```
EDITOR = "vim"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue with the following:

1. For the first issue (108 was set as my prompt), I went into my `.zshrc` file and added `export PS1="%/$ "`, then saved the file. My command prompt instantly changed back to normal, and I was fine.
2. For the second issue (echo $EDITOR was not returning anything, so tmux was not generating new projects), I simply entered my .zshrc file, and I added `export` before `EDITOR` so that the line looked like `export EDITOR="vim"`.